# Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. Component calls setState inside useEffect,..., or one of the dependencies changes on every render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, rtk-query

I have error like in title. But I don't know how my dependencie change every render because it is in useEffect. I suspected it was related to the map function so I moved it higher in the hierarchy to "injectEndpoints"->"transformResponse" but that didn't help. I don't know how to change it or maybe that's not the point?

```
export const parametersApi = myApi
  .injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
      getParameters: builder.query<
        ExtendedParameter[],
        string
      >({
        query: (id) =>
          `/${id}/parameters`,
        providesTags: (_result, _error, id) => [
          {
            type: `Parameters`,
            id: `PLIST_${id}`,
          },
        ],
        transformResponse: (response: parameter[]) => {
          return response.map((param) => {
            return { id: param.name, ...param };
          });
        },
      }),

....
export const {
  useGetParametersQuery } = parametersApi;
```

The file in which the error occurs:

```
  const selectedParameters =
    useGetParametersQuery(master.id, {
      skip: !master,
    }).data || [];
...
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("selectedParameters", selectedParameters);
    setParameters(selectedParameters);
  }, [selectedParameters]);
```

[console.log("selectedParameters", selectedParameters);](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjv2j.png)

Comment: `useGetParametersQuery` is probably generating a new object every render, triggering `useEffect` which triggers another render etc... You'll need to show the code for that hook.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton `useGetParametersQuery ` comes from the destructuring of parametersApi, it seems to me that there may be a mistake in transformResponse where I use map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 || []
```

creates a new array every render while there is no `.data` yet - so `selectedParameters` will be a new reference and trigger an `useEffect` every time.

Do something like `const EMPTY_ARR = []` **outside your component** and do  `|| EMPTY_ARR` to keep a stable reference here.

Comment: Thank you! It's worked. Could you explain why I create array outside the component and why then the reference is stable?

Comment: Because you do it once - the file executes only once. But your component function executes every render. So every render, you create a new empty array - and `[] !== []`, so the `useEffect` triggers again.